# python - preprocessor function prints with wrong if condition value

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, preprocessor-directive

If I define a function with a preprocessor like in C, and then call it inside an if, it runs even though the if should be false.

```
#define HELLO \
{ \
    print("hello world") \
}

i = 1
if i == 2:
    HELLO
```

This one prints hello.

If I do an ordinary function like this

```
def hello():
    print("hello world")

i = 1
if i == 2:
    hello()
```

then it doesn't do that.

Why is the difference please? I know the brackets are different but I tried both of them with and without the brackets and it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the first snippet supposed to be a ‘C’ like language and the second supposed to be python?

Comment: I am using preprocessor in python like in C

Comment: Or I am trying to

Comment: Which preprocessor are you using?

Comment: but it prints hello even though the if value is not equal

Comment: I don't understand, I just run the program

Comment: How would I find out what the preprocessor is called?

Comment: If Tom is correct, there must also be an error traceback. Do you get one?

Comment: Who is Tom? I can't see anything from Tom

Comment: Oh sorry the answer. I'll read it.

Comment: The one answer so far is from Tom. Very insightful it is too.

Comment: quamrana there isn't an error

Comment: Oh, yes, I see now. Try it with ‘i = 2’ and you should see it.

Comment: The bottom line is that there is no preprocessor, do not even think about it, just write your code.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have a builtin preprocessor.  The macro defintion isn't doing what you expect:

```
#define HELLO \
{ \
    print("hello world") \
}
```

The first line begins with `#`, so Python treats it as a comment.  The line ends with a continuation `\`, but the comment still ends after the first line.  The entire thing is equivalent to:

```
{print("hello world")}
```

This calls `print`, which prints `hello world`, then creates a `set` with the result, which is `None`.

If you want to use the C preprocessor, you will need to explicitly invoke it before passing the result to Python.

Comment: Thank you, how do I do the preprocessor?

Comment: Also I tried to thumbs up the answer but it still says 0

Comment: Why is the question -1?

Comment: Using Unix-style shell syntax, you can run the preprocessor on a Python file as `gcc -E - < file1.py > file2.py`  This will proprocess `file1.py` and place the result in `file2.py`.  Just beware that the C proprocessor was not designed with Python in mind, so you need to exercise care if you use it.  But you're actually better off avoiding it entirely.  Python doesn't really need a preprocessor since it's a dynamic, interpreted language.  In your case, you can just replace `HELLO` with a function, and call the function where needed.